# Email not sent when new item created in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, power-automate

I am new to sharepoint and learning to use it via youtube videos. I created list with columns. Not I want to send an email when an item is created. I use powerautomate to create workflows.

I want to trigger a flow when an item is created. So, I used "item is created" trigger and an action to send email. While trying to test the workflow, it says "Test by adding new item to sharepoint folder". Are sharepoint folder and sharepoint list different? Anyways I try to add a new item and the workflow keeps loading ending up in a timeout.

I then used the trigger "item or file is modified", this sent the email succesfully.

I then tried using the trigger "item is created or modified". While testing this it says "workflow is ready, test the flow by modifying item". It doesnt say anything about adding item. So, I tried modifying and an email was sent but when I add a new item, no email this time.

I have been breaking my head for the past 3 hours, watching many youtube videos and forums but I cant find the issue.

Comment: Sorry to hear you are having a hard time with this, would you be able to take a screenshot of each action (blurring out any confidential information of course).  There is probably something really simple that is not right.  Also, make sure Flow is turned ON.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint only libraries support create folders. Please create the below Microsoft flow:

1.Add "**When a file is created (properties only)**" Trigger

2.Add "**Get file properties**" action

3.Add "**Send an email (V2)**" action

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation

Comment: Hi Nisha Balan. I am glad to be able to help you. If the answer is helpful to you, you can accept it as answer. The behavior will help others who meet the similar issue in the future quickly find the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you would like to send an email when a new item is added to the list using power automate. I will try to help you with question you have and I will also suggest you some other options.

**Little Info-**

Sharepoint List -

In normal language a SharePoint List is kind of table with rows and columns which can hold different type of information like single line text, Multiline text, number, users and etc.
Ref - [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-lists-0a1c3ace-def0-44af-b225-cfa8d92c52d7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyYPA.png)

**Steps**

- Have a sharepoint List - I have list "SendEmail" with few columns here

  Subject : Single Line text Column

  Email Body : Multiline text Column

  SendTo : User Column

[image]

- Create New Power automate flow - There are multiple ways to create flow

  option 1 - Create flow from List. Screenshot for reference
  [image]
  option 2 - Create flow from power automate site - flow.microsoft.com
  [image]
- Select/Enter Site Url and List Name
  [image]
- Add New Step  "Send Email" Activity - Start typing 'Email'.. You will get multiple results… select one highlighted in below screenshot
  [image]
- Fill in information.
  [image]
- Save the flow and Test by adding new item in list
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the "Alert Me" feature of the SharePoint list which sends an email notification.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the answers. Surprisingly it worked after 4 hours with the same workflow. I was working with the trigger at night from 11pm-3am. Around 2.30 am it worked all of a sudden.
Yesterday from mrng till evng I created two more flows and all of them were working. But at 1.30 am night there were issues in the flow all of a sudden which was working till yesterday evng. The site name was not showing in the site address box in trigger. It said connection expired, try a new connection. After debugging for sometime I found out that the connection to outlook365 was lost as per powerautomate app.
But my outlook mail was working fine, I could send and receive emails. Now today at 4.30pm all of a sudden I can enter the site address.

Its weird that powerautomate is working during mrng and not at night. Is anyone facing this issue? I live in the middle east.